# Why do I get "This field is required" error from Django imageField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have problems with Django's image field. It says that the image field is empty even though I have selected an image
This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads")
```

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import PostForm

def postsite(request):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
        return redirect('post')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

And this is my post.html:

```
    <form action="" method="POST" enctyppe="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Post">
    </form>
```

After I have selected an image for the imageField and submitted the form, the output of this code `print(form.errors)` is:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>picture<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Because of other discussions about this error I tried to add this to my form:

```
 enctyppe="multipart/form-data"
```

However, the error still persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in your form action `enctyppe=`.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctyppe="multipart/form-data">
```

Should be:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```